# Can SIFT algorithm extract feature in real-time speed on PC?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision, sift

In page 25 of David Lowe's paper "Distinctive Image Features from Scale-Invariant Keypoints" in 2004, he claims, "Their computation is efficient, so that several thousand keypoints can be extracted from a typical image with near real-time performance on standard PC hardware." 
Here is the link: http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf

However, I tested SIFT algorithm using Andrea Vedaldi's sift++(aka VLFeat), which is a c++ implementation, on a 640x480 image, and it cost 0.839 second to extract about 3000 keypoints from one image. My PC is Intel i7 2600k, with 16GB RAM.
Here is the link of the code: http://www.vlfeat.org/~vedaldi/code/siftpp.html

To be honest, I think it's quite weird if SIFT can achieve real-time speed, since it has to extract so much keypoints from one image.

Does anybody knows how fast is SIFT on a modern PC?

Comment: I'm wondering if you have a typo somewhere there. 640x480=~300_000 pixels. "3000 thousand" would mean about 10 key points for every pixel in the image. Did you mean just "3000", or have I missed something crucial here?

Comment: Have you looked at using a GPU: http://www.cs.unc.edu/~ccwu/siftgpu/ ? The benchmark on that site says it can process up to 27 frames per second using CUDA

Comment: @Jerry Coffin sorry, it's 3000, not 3000 thousand^_^

Comment: @Pablo, I do not aim to accelerate the algorithm, I just want to compare the speed of several algorithm on PC. So I need to know the real speed of SIFT on a PC(not on other hardware).

Comment: @user1222309 one could argue that a GFX card is "standard PC hardware"

Comment: @drhirsch haha, ok, let me give it a speicific definition. Running on a standard PC means running on CPU only.

Comment: @user1222309 Ok :-) But actually I was citing David Lowe - maybe he was referring to CUDA?

Comment: Just glancing over the source, I see that no vectorization is used, although some of the routines look like they could be vectorized. And a vector unit is part of a standard CPU, even back in 2004. So I hazard a guess, that the code could be accelerated several times if it would only use the resources of a standard CPU.

Comment: Just make the images smaller, any algorithm on any hardware can  run at "real-time" (which is a poorly defined phrase in this context) given a sufficiently small input image

Answer (score 0):

May be this article provide some insight about your question...Article actually includes parallelized versiob of SIFT but performance with one core version is also given.

[Paralellization of SIFT](http://www.iiswc.org/iiswc2008/sildes/1-2.pdf)